# Linux process cpu user ticks delta is bigger than system user ticks delta

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

My program samples /proc data in order to get statistic about the CPU usage of the system.
I sample both /proc/stat and calculate the statistics delta (in interval of 1 second),
and I also sample the process /proc/pid/stat user ticks and system ticks.
This is an exmaple of log from my system:

```
From /proc/stat(total System)- UserTicksDelta: 9, niceTicksDelta: 0, SystemTicksDelta: 3, IrqTicksDelta: 0,     SoftIRQDelta: 0, IdleTicksDelta: 0, iowaitTicksDelta: 71, sinceLastUpadteMilli: 1007

Process 18643 - userTicksDelta: 20, SystemTicksDelta: 3 SinceLastUpdateMilli: 1006
```

The samples are collected one after each other(no delay between them, I confirmed it with the log's timestamp).

As you can see the user ticks delta of the process is bigger than the total system user ticks delta.
Also you can notice that the iowait is very high, and this problem occures only when the IOWait is high.

How is it possible that a specific process user ticks delta is bigger than the total system? It can be somehow related to the IOWait? Maybe the process uses the IOWait ticks as user ticks but it's reported as IOWait and not user ticks in the system level?

I run on RedHat release 6.4.

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: your question is ... ?

Comment: How is it possible that a specific process user ticks delta is bigger than the total system? It can be somehow related to the IOWait? Maybe the process uses the IOWait ticks as user ticks but it's reported as IOWait and not user ticks in the system level?

Comment: Someone else has [a similar problem](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-kernel/2014-02/msg00030.html).